# Let $y$ be real, $n$ is natural, and $\varepsilon>0$. For some $\delta>0$, if $u$ is real and $|u-y|<\delta$, then $|u^{n}-y^{n}|<\varepsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, induction, epsilon-delta

I've almost got this problem solved, and I need a(some) pointer(s) as to finishing this problem up (which will be greatly appreciated [!]).  Here is the full, problem statement in its exact form.

***Problem:*** Given $y\in\mathbb{R}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and $\varepsilon>0$, show that for some $\delta>0$, if $u\in\mathbb{R}$ and $|u-y|<\delta$ then $|u^{n}-y^{n}|<\varepsilon$.

***Preliminary Notes/Work:*** Now, the question additionally provides a hint to prove the inequality for $n=1$ and $n=2$, then to use induction on $n$ and use the identity of $u^{n}-y^{n}=(u-y)(u^{n-1}+yu^{n-2}+\cdots+y^{n-2}u+y^{n-1})$. I've made it as far as defining the induction hypothesis for some $n$ and I've used the identity to work the inequalities in order to show the statement holds for $n$, but I can't find a way out from there.

So, proceeding by induction, we have for the case when $n=1$ that we can simply let $\delta=\varepsilon$. Then, letting $y\in\mathbb{R}$, and taking $\varepsilon>0$, let $\delta=\varepsilon>0$. When $u\in\mathbb{R}$ this implies that when $|u-y|<\delta=\varepsilon$, then clearly $|u^{1}-y^{1}|=|u-y|<\varepsilon$.

For the case when $n=2$, we let $\delta=\min\bigg\{1,\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2|y|+1}\bigg\}$. Now, when $u\in\mathbb{R}$ and $|u-y|<\delta$, then $|u-y|<1$ in particular. Further, by the Reverse Triangle Inequality, we then have that $|u|-|y|\leq |u-y|<1$. Adding $|2y|$ to both sides yields that $|u|+|y|\leq |u-y|+|2y|<1+|2y|$. Again by the Triangle Inequality we have that $|u+y|\leq |u|+|y|<2|y|+1$, and so $|u+y|<2|y|+1$. We now compute $|u^{2}-y^{2}|=|u+y||u-y|<(2|y|+1)\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2|y|+1}=\varepsilon$. Thus, the result hold also when $n=2$, and we can conclude the base case holds.

For the inductive hypothesis we have that for $y\in\mathbb{R}$, $n-1\in\mathbb{N}$, and $\varepsilon>0$, there is some $\delta>0$ such that if $u\in\mathbb{R}$ and $|u-y|<\delta$ then $|u^{n-1}-y^{n-1}|<\varepsilon$. We need to show this result holds for $n$.

I've been messing around with this, and I keep getting nowhere. We have that when $|u-y|<\delta$ then:

$|u^{n}-y^{n}|=|u-y||u^{n-1}+yu^{n-2}+\cdots+y^{n-2}u+y^{n-1}|$

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\!<\delta|u^{n-1}+yu^{n-2}+\cdots+y^{n-2}u+y^{n-1}|$.

I just need to find the $\delta$ in this case, and, at first, I wanted to let $\delta=\dfrac{\varepsilon}{u^{n-1}+yu^{n-2}+\cdots+y^{n-2}u+y^{n-1}}$, but (I think) the problem statement asserts that $\delta$ can't depend on $u$, or can it?  If it can, then I'm done...but if not , which $\delta$ will work?  Please note, this problem is a homework problem, and if one decides not to provide a solution (which I completely understand), then please provide suggestions, recommendations, hints, etc. I figured since I'm almost done with the problem, providing a solution wouldn't hurt, but anything will be GREATLY appreciated!  Thank you for your time reading this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The way you're trying to do it doesn't require induction

$\delta$ can't depend on $u$ but it can depend on $y$. Note that $|u|<|u-y|+|y|<|y|+\delta$.
$$
\Big{|}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}y^ju^{n-1-j}\Big{|}<\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}|y|^j|u|^{n-1-j}<\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}|y|^{j}(|y|+\delta)^{n-1-j}={(|y|+\delta)^{n}-|y|^{n}\over\delta} 
$$
So we want to have $$\delta{(|y|+\delta)^{n}-|y|^{n}\over\delta}<\varepsilon
\implies (|y|+\delta)^{n}<{\varepsilon}+|y|^n\\
\implies\delta<\left({\varepsilon}+|y|^n\right)^{1\over n}-|y|=:K$$
So picking $\delta=0.5K$ suffices.

> The inductive way

$$|u^{n}-y^n|=|(u^{n-1}-y^{n-1})(u+y)+uy^{n-1}-yu^{n-1}|\\<|u^{n-1}-y^{n-1}||u+y|+|uy||y^{n-2}-u^{n-2}|$$
Now there exists $\delta_1,\delta_2>0:|u^{n-1}-y^{n-1}|<{0.5\varepsilon\over2|y|+1}$ whenever $|u-y|<\delta_1$ and $|u^{n-2}-y^{n-2}|<{0.5\varepsilon\over|y|(|y|+1)}$ whenever $|u-y|<\delta_2$. If we pick $0<\delta<\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2,1\}$ those inequalities still hold if $|u-y|<\delta$, moreover we have $|u|<|y|+\delta<|y|+1$. So
$$
|u-y|<\delta\implies|u^{n}-y^n|<0.5\varepsilon{|u+y|\over2|y|+1}+0.5\varepsilon{|u||y|\over|y|(|y|+1)}\\<0.5\varepsilon{|u|+|y|\over2|y|+1}+0.5\varepsilon{|u|\over(|y|+1)}<0.5\varepsilon+0.5\varepsilon=\varepsilon
$$

> Book's method(?)

$$
|u^{m-j}y^{j}+u^jy^{m-j}|=|u|^j|y|^j|u^{m-j}+y^{m-j}|<|u|^j|y|^j(|u^{m-j}-y^{m-j}|+2|y|^{m-j})
$$
For $j=0,1,..,n-1$ we can find $\delta_j>0:|u^{n-1-j}-y^{n-1-j}|<{1\over n\{(|y|+1)|y|\}^j}$ whenever $|u-y|<\delta_j$. Pick $0<\delta<\min(\{\delta_j:0\le j\le n-1\}\cup\{1\})$.
$$
|u-y|<\delta\implies|u^n-y^n|<\delta\Big{|}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}u^{n-1-j}y^j\Big{|}<\delta\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor {n\over 2}\rfloor}|u^{n-1-j}y^j+y^{n-1-j}u^j|\\
<\delta\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor {n\over 2}\rfloor}(|u||y|)^j\left({1\over n\{(|y|+1)|y|\}^j}+2|y|^{n-1-j}\right)\\
<\delta\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor {n\over 2}\rfloor}\left({1\over n}+2|u|^j|y|^{n-1}\right)
$$
Now $$\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor {n\over 2}\rfloor}|u|^j|y|^{n-1}<|y|^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor {n\over 2}\rfloor}(|y|+1)^j=:S$$
Therefore
$$
|u^n-y^n|<\delta\left({{\lfloor {n\over 2}\rfloor}+1\over n}+2S\right)<\delta(1+2S)
$$
So picking $0<\delta<\min(\{\delta_j:0\le j\le n-1\}\cup\{1,{\varepsilon\over1+2S}\})$ suffices.

Comment: Thank you VERY much for your help. I like both of your solutions MUCH better than what the textbook suggests to do!  I'm going to start reworking this corresponding to your inductive solution above. Any insight as to how the solution is determined per the book's method? If not, no big deal...again, I like your, more sensible, solutions better, and I voted them accordingly (especially after your first edit).  Thank you again, and best wishes!

Comment: @Procore I've updated my answer. Book's method mimics your answer for case $n=2$.

Comment: How elegant of a solution! I'll be sure to rigorously study the update in your post. I'm currently starting out in an Advanced Calculus One course, and, and we started C. Pugh's, "Real Analysis" (great book so far [!] I must say). The first chapter is broad, and some postponed, after thoughts of mine, once I drafted a solution, got me to discover the book's solution may be going for the use of the trichotomy property of $\mathbb{R}$ with the estimate for $n>0$ of $0<a<b$, $b^{n}-a^{n}\leq(b-a)nb^{n-1}$ along with the inductive hypothesis might solve it (I'll be sure to check).

Answer (score 0):

Let $n\in\mathbb Z_{>0}$ be given and let $f$ be the real-valued function defined by $f(x):=x^n.$ Then $f$ is [clearly continuous](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Polynomial_is_Continuous), which means that for all $x\in\mathbb R$ and $\forall\varepsilon>0$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that $|f(z)-f(x)|=|z^n-x^n|<\varepsilon$ whenever $z\in\mathbb R$ and $|z-x|<\delta.$